# Can every regular polygon be drawn on regular square grid?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, euclidean-geometry

Is it possible to draw every regular polygon with an even number of vertices on a regular square grid graph? I am lost with this, it works for all cases I've checked but does it work for all regular $n$-gons where $n$ is even?

Comment: Where do you find that regular polygons can be drawn on a square grid?  It does not work even for an equilateral triangle unless we use three dimensions, nor for a regular oentagon even with added dimensions!

Comment: Have you managed a hexagon?

Comment: You cannot draw any regular polygon except a square in the integer grid: http://jdh.hamkins.org/no-regular-polygons-in-the-integer-lattice/

Comment: -1 for being vague and not including your attempts.

Answer (score 2):

If you can do $2n$ then you can do $n$

But you cannot do $7$ even with a ruler and compass (and you can construct a grid with a ruler and compass) so you cannot do $14$ with a grid